# Why index made this query slower?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Table has 1 500 000 records, 1 250 000 of them have field = 'z'.
I need select random not 'z' field.

```
$random = mt_rand(1, 250000);  
$query = "SELECT field FROM table WHERE field != 'z' LIMIT $random, 1";
```

It is working ok.

Then I decided to optimize it and indexed `field` in table.

Result was strange - it was **slower ~3 times**. I tested it.
Why it is slower? Is not such indexing should make it faster?

my ISAM

```
explain with index:  
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key   key_len  ref  rows     Extra  
1   SIMPLE       table  range field          field 758      NULL 1139287  Using  

explain without index:  
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows     Extra  
1   SIMPLE       table  ALL   NULL           NULL NULL     NULL 1484672  Using where
```

Comment: What engine it is? Show output of EXPLAIN

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Summary**

The problem is that `field` is not a good candidate for indexing, due to the nature of [b-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btree).

**Explanation**

Let's suppose you have a table that has the results of 500,000 coin tosses, where the toss is either `1` (heads) or `0` (tails):

```
CREATE TABLE toss (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    result int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)

select result, count(*) from toss group by result order by result;
+--------+----------+
| result | count(*) |
+--------+----------+
|      0 |   250290 |
|      1 |   249710 |
+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.40 sec)
```

If you want to select one toss (at random) where the toss was tails, then you need to search through your table, picking a random starting place.

```
select * from toss where result != 1 limit 123456, 1;
+--------+--------+
| id     | result |
+--------+--------+
| 246700 |      0 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

explain select * from toss where result != 1 limit 123456, 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | toss  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 500000 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

You see that you're basically searching sequentially through all of the rows to find a match.

If you create an index on the `toss` field, then your index will contain two values, each with roughly 250,000 entries.

```
create index foo on toss ( result );
Query OK, 500000 rows affected (2.48 sec)
Records: 500000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

select * from toss where result != 1 limit 123456, 1;
+--------+--------+
| id     | result |
+--------+--------+
| 246700 |      0 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.25 sec)

explain select * from toss where result != 1 limit 123456, 1;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | toss  | range | foo           | foo  | 4       | NULL | 154565 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Now you're searching fewer records, but the time to search increased from 0.06 to 0.25 seconds.  Why?  Because sequentially scanning an index is actually less efficient than sequentially scanning a table, for indexes with a large number of rows for a given key.

Let's look at the indexes on this table:

```
show index from toss;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| toss  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |      500000 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| toss  |          1 | foo      |            1 | result      | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

The PRIMARY index is a good index: there are 500,000 rows, and there are 500,000 values.  Arranged in a BTREE, you can quickly identify a single row based on the id.

The foo index is a bad index:  there are 500,000 rows, but only 2 possible values.  This is pretty much the worst possible case for a BTREE -- all of the overhead of searching the index, and still having to search through the results.

Comment: So we should only use  Indices if the values have a high variety (like primary key - one for each row). What do you suggest OP should do in his case? Simply drop the index, fin?

Comment: @Blauhirn if the index is hurting, not helping, then yes, drop the index. Beyond that, you might want to restructure (denormalize) the data to make it easier to select the interesting data, but that really depends upon detailed information not present in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an `order by` clause, that `LIMIT $random, 1` starts at some undefined place.

And according to your explain, the index isn't even being used.

Comment: so if I add `ORDER BY id` will it be used?